# Select one row from multiple rows based on availability

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

- **Emp** (Id(PK), Name)
- **Address** (AddressId(PK), AddressType)
- **EmpAddress** (EmpId(FK), AddresId(FK))

One employee may have multiple address.

Sample data:

**Emp**

```
1 abc
2 pqr
```

**Address**

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

**EmpAddress**

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

Here empid 1 has all 3 addresses.

I want the only one address at a time based on availability.

- If adresstype a is available then display only a
- If adresstype c is available then display only c
- If adresstype b is available then display only b

Priority is a->c->b

If only one available then display that without any Priority .

I wrote this query, but it is not working:

```
select * 
from Emp
inner join EmpAddress on Emp.Id = .EmpAddress .Emp
inner join Address on Address.Id = EmpAddress.Address_Id
where AddressType is NOT NULL
  and AddressType = case
                       when AddressType = 'a' then 'a'
                       when AddressType = 'c' then 'c'
                       when AddressType = 'b' then 'b'
                    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a numerical priority to each address type based on the ordering `a > c > b`.  Then, subquery to retain only the highest ranking address for each employee.

```
SELECT Id, Emp, AddressType
FROM
(
    SELECT e.Id, ea.Emp, a.AddressType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.Id
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.AddressType = 'a' THEN 1
                          WHEN a.AddressType = 'b' THEN 2
                          WHEN a.AddressType = 'c' THEN 3 END) rn
    FROM Emp e
    INNER JOIN EmpAddress ea
        ON e.Id = ea.Emp
    INNER JOIN Address a
        ON a.Id = ea.Address_Id
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Getting this error : No column name was specified for column 50 of 't'.

Comment: @HimanshuSuthar Sorry, I forgot to alias the call to `ROW_NUMBER`.  Try the updated answer.

Comment: thanks but now getting this error: The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: @HimanshuSuthar I fixed that problem too.  Keep in mind we can't test our queries (easily) because you provided us with zero data.

Comment: Not to mention that self-explanatory error messages ought to be fixable without help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   Emp e
       cross apply
       (
           select top 1 ea.AddresId, a.AddressType 
           from   EmpAddress ea
                  inner join Address a on ea.AddresId = a.AddresId
           where  ea.EmpId = e.Id
           order by case a.AddressType 
                         when 'a' then 1 
                         when 'c' then 2 
                         when 'b' then 3 
                         end
       ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also retrieve the records based on Priority via *TOP(1)* with `TIES`

```
SELECT 
        TOP(1) with TIES e.Id, *
FROM Emp e
INNER JOIN EmpAddress ea ON e.Id = ea.Emp
INNER JOIN Address a ON a.Id = ea.Address_Id
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.Id ORDER BY 
                             CASE (a.AddressType) WHEN 'a' THEN 1
                                    WHEN 'c' THEN 2 WHEN 'b' THEN 3 END)
```